# Tensorflow estimator: Different epoch number gives the same result

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want to create a simple model using TF Estimator. Below is my code:

```
num_epoch = 4
num_train = 186
num_test = 81

# 1 Define input function
def input_function(x, y, is_train):

    dict_x = {
        "featurename" : x,
    }

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
        dict_x, y
    ))

    if is_train:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(num_train, seed=113).repeat(num_epoch).batch(num_train)
    else:   
        dataset = dataset.batch(num_test)
    return dataset

def my_serving_input_fn2():
    input_data = {
        "featurename" : tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 15], name='inputtensors')
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(input_data, input_data)


def main(argv):
    tf.set_random_seed(113)
    np.random.seed(113)
    run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_summary_steps=None, save_checkpoints_secs=None, tf_random_seed=113)

    # 2 Define feature columns
    feature_columns = [
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="featurename",shape=15),
    ]

    # 3 Define an estimator
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=feature_columns,
        hidden_units=[15, 15],
        n_classes=3,
        optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
        activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
        model_dir = 'models/',
        config=run_config
    )

    # Train the model
    classifier.train(
        input_fn=lambda:input_function(X_train, y_train, True)
    )

    # Evaluate the model
    eval_result = classifier.evaluate(
        input_fn=lambda:input_function(X_test, y_test, False)
    )

    print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**eval_result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
    tf.app.run(main)
```

I believe the model will be trained `num_epoch` times as `num_epoch` affect dataset's `repeat()`. I didn't define `steps` in estimator so it will be trained forever until `input_fn` generates the `tf.errors.OutOfRange`.

But if I change `num_epoch` value it always gives the same result. For example, when I run this program with `num_epoch=4` and `num_epoch=400` the test set accuracy will be the same.

Am I misunderstanding the training process here? or it's just a coincidence? I hope someone can help explain why this happened

Comment: I'm not certain, but it may be because you're fixing the random seed as 113, so each shuffle produces the same random ordering. Try it without fixing the random seed and see if anything changes,

Comment: I just tried it, but unfortunately, the results are the same

Comment: Could you provide more details about your situation? What is your current accuracy? Is the accuracy still the same between `num_epoch=4` and `num_epoch=400` if you try different hyperparameters (e.g. `hidden_units=[20, 20]`)? How large are your training and test sets?

Comment: the model's accuracy still depends on the architecture (e.g. hidden units, learning rate, optimization algorithm) but the number of  epochs never change the result

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you don't have enough data. What are you doing is training it over the same data and hits a peak of "intelligence". Increase your dataset basically and you will see changes in your `num-epoch`.

Comment: I don't think so, please see my reply to @ninjin's comment